# Delete "subpath" from Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I know Azure doesn't have actual subpaths, but if I have for example `container/projectID/iterationNumber/filename.jpg` and I delete a project, how can I delete from `ProjectID`? Is it possible through coding?

I don't want to use the azure application as I am creating a web app.

Thanks in Advance

**EDIT**:

This is the code provided by Microsoft to target on specific item:

```
// Retrieve storage account from connection string.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the blob client.
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

// Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

// Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob.txt".
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob.txt");

// Delete the blob.
blockBlob.Delete();
```

**SystemDesignModel**

```
    public static SystemDesign returnImageURL(IListBlobItem item)
    {

        if (item is CloudBlockBlob)
        {
            var blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
            return new SystemDesign
            {
                URL = blob.Uri.ToString(),
            };

        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know, blob storage does not have the concept of subfolders. It has just 2 level hierarchy - `container` & `blobs`. So in essence, a subfolder is just a prefix that you attach to blob name. In your example, the actual file you uploaded is `filename.jpg` but its name from blob storage perspective is `projectID/iterationNumber/filename.jpg`.

Since there is no concept of subfolder, you just can't delete it like we do on our local computer. However there's a way. Blob storage provides a way to `search for blobs starting with a certain blob prefix`. So what you have to do is first list all blobs that start with certain prefix (`projectID` in your case) and then delete the blobs one at a time returned as a result of listing operations.

Take a look at sample code below:

```
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
        var container = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("container");
        BlobContinuationToken token = null;
        do
        {
            var listingResult = container.ListBlobsSegmented("blob-prefix (projectID in your case)", true, BlobListingDetails.None, 5000, token, null, null);
            token = listingResult.ContinuationToken;
            var blobs = listingResult.Results;
            foreach (var blob in blobs)
            {
                (blob as ICloudBlob).DeleteIfExists();
                Console.WriteLine(blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + " deleted.");
            }
        }
        while (token != null);
```

Comment: @Guarav Mantri The var `listingResult = container.ListBlobsSegmented("15", token);` is returning a 404 error even though I Know it exists

Comment: Did you change the "container" name to match with your container's name here - `var container = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("container");`?

Comment: Oh ok, fixed that.. but the `blob as ICloudBlob).DeleteIfExists()` is pointing to a null reference. I'll check why

Comment: `(blob as ICloudBlob).DeleteIfExists();` ... my bad! Sorry, I didn't check the code by running it. Please try doing something like `(blob as CloudBlockBlob).DeleteIfExists();`.

Comment: Still the same, if it helps,  I edited my code to show my Design Model / instance

Comment: I have updated the call the `ListBlobsSegmented` method. Please try it with the updated call and that should work. I just tried it on my end and it worked.